# Fetch user information in Resource Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have configured the resource server which verify JWT token against auth server. In code bellow you can see my configuration which has defined `issuer-uri` (is URI from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)). If user is authenticated on my public client against Auth0, this client receive JWT token from Auth0. When I call resource server with token header, user is authorized, and resources are available, but `SecurityContextHolder` contains only base data parsed from JWT, and not whole information about user. I have available `userinfo` endpoint from Auth0 which provides user's name, picture, email, etc.

My question is if I can set this user info endpoint in my resource server, to fetch this information automatically or what is the best way to do that? I would like to have this informations in `SecurityContextHolder` or at least user's email and user's name.

```java
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    return http.build()
}
```

and JWT decoder bean

```java
@Bean
fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder? {
    val jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation<JwtDecoder>(issuer) as NimbusJwtDecoder
    val audienceValidator: OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> = AudienceValidator(audience)
    val withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer)
    val withAudience: OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> = DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator(withIssuer, audienceValidator)
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience)
    return jwtDecoder
}
```

File `application.properties`

```java
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=my-domain.com
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audience=my-audience
```

EDIT
This is payload of JWT received from Auth0

```
{
  "iss": "https://dev-abcdefgh.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "google-oauth2|353335637216442227159",
  "aud": [
    "my-audience",
    "https://dev-3ag8q43b.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1663100248,
  "exp": 1663186648,
  "azp": "m01yBdKdQd5erBxriQde24ogfsdAsYvD",
  "scope": "openid profile email"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Note On Efficiency

**Do not call user endpoint when building the security-context for a request on a resource-server with JWT decoder.**

Auth0 can issue JWT access-token and JWTs can be decoded / validated on the resource-server without a round trip to the authorization-server.

Calling the user-info endpoint for each and every of your resource-server incoming request would be a drop in latency (and efficiency).

#### Add User Info to Auth0 Access Tokens

In Auth0 management console, go to `Auth Pipeline` -> `Rules` and click `Create` to add a rule like:

```
function addUserInfoToAccessToken(user, context, callback) {
  context.accessToken['https://stackoverflow.com/user'] = user;
  return callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Et voilà! You now have a `https://stackoverflow.com/user` private claim in access-tokens. You can (should?) narrow to the [user attributes](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules/user-object-in-rules) you actually need in your resource-server (what is accessed in your `@PreAuthorize` expressions for instance).

#### Complete Resource Server

`JwtAuthenticationToken`, Spring-security default `Authentication` implementation for resource-servers with JWT decoder, exposes all of the access-token claims, including the private one we added.

Here is a complete sample using the private claim from above in different ways (security expression, and inside @Controller method), but I recommand you go through this [first 3 of those tutorials I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), you'll find useful tips to make the best usage of private claims in spring-security:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Auth0DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Auth0DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/access-token-user-info")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public static class DemoController {

        @GetMapping("/{nickname}")
        @PreAuthorize("#nickname eq authentication.tokenAttributes['https://stackoverflow.com/user']['nickname']")
        public Map<String, Object> getGreeting(@PathVariable String nickname, JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
            return auth.getToken().getClaimAsMap("https://stackoverflow.com/user");
        }
    }

    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public static class SecurityConf {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

            // Enable and configure CORS
            http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

            // State-less session (state in access-token only)
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
            http.csrf().disable();

            // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 403 (redirect to login) when authorization is missing or invalid
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
            });

            return http.build();
        }

        private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            // Very permissive CORS config...
            final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

            // Limited to API routes (neither actuator nor Swagger-UI)
            final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/access-token-user-info/**", configuration);

            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

With just this property:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
```

And that pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.c4soft</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth0-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth0-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and Auth0 with user-data in access-token</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And now the output of a call to `http://localhost:8080/access-token-user-info/ch4mp` with Postman (and an access-token for ch4mp):

```json
{
    "clientID": "...",
    "email_verified": true,
    "roles": [
        "PLAYER"
    ],
    "created_at": "2021-08-16T21:03:02.086Z",
    "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/....png",
    "global_client_id": "...",
    "identities": [
        {
            "isSocial": false,
            "provider": "auth0",
            "user_id": "...",
            "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication"
        }
    ],
    "updated_at": "2022-09-26T20:53:08.957Z",
    "user_id": "auth0|...",
    "permissions": [
        "solutions:manage"
    ],
    "name": "ch4mp@c4-soft.com",
    "nickname": "ch4mp",
    "_id": "...",
    "persistent": {},
    "email": "ch4mp@c4-soft.com",
    "last_password_reset": "2022-09-24T16:39:00.152Z"
}
```

#### Note on Tokens

**Do not use ID tokens as access-tokens**, this is a [worst practice](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/). Authorization-server emmits different kind of tokens for different usages:

- access-token: destined to resource-server. It should be very short lived (minutes) so that if leaked or revoked, the consequences are limited. Clients should:

  - just use it as `Bearer` `Authorization` header in the requests sent to the right `audience`. In the case you have different audience, your client must maintain different access-tokens (for instance one for "your" API and other ones for Google, Facebook or whatever other API your client consumes directly).
  - not try to decode access-tokens, it is a contract between authorization and resource servers and they can decide to change the format at any moment (breaking the client if it expects to "understand" that token)
- ID token: destined to client. Such tokens aim at communicating signed user data. As it is generally quite long lived, the consequences of it being leaked could be a real problem if used for access-control. Read article linked earlier for more reasons why not to use it for access-control.
- refresh-token: long lived, to be used by client only and sent to authorization-server only. Authorization-server should carefully control the origin of tokens refreshing requests and clients be very careful with who they send such tokens to (consequences of a leak can be dramatic).

Comment: you said "not try to decode access-tokens", you also suggest add user info into access token. do you mean not try to decode access-tokens on client side?

Comment: Yes, exactly: ID token is to be used by client and access-token by resource-server => If you need more data in a REST API security-context, have authorization-server add it into access-token. If you need it on the client (display info or hide / show UI elements like menu entries), add it to ID token.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have this informations in SecurityContextHolder or at
> least user's email and user's name.

Have you seen what's inside your jwt token?
Did you add openid scope in your authentication process? if so there should be an IdToken in your auth server response json body, inside IdToken jwt token claim there are various information about the user's data such user's name and email.
Other user attributes can also be added by adding custom claim to your jwt token, after adding those claims then you can try to access it via SecurityContextHolder.

[Reference link](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/create-custom-claims)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Yes, I am aware of this data in Idtoken, but I would like to fetch information about current user in resource server. For instance, we have endpoints like `update-portfolio` without any aditional ids in path. So in this case we find out who is current user and we update his portfolio. There are more use-cases like this in our app.

Comment: yea great then whats holding you back? you can access these information via SecurityContextHolder, get the Authentication object that holds the Principal data, the Principal object should hold the data you need

Comment: I tried add principal as Controller parameter, but it contains only data parsed from JWT, it doesn't fetch data from userInfo endpoint automatically. So I didn't know how to do that. I thought in previous version of spring resource server, was userInfo endpoint possible set in properties but now it isn't

Comment: can you show us the code of your Controller? I looked into the Auth0 documentation and it quite clear on how to do this have you tried following the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/01-login#show-user-profile-information)?

Comment: I believe that data from the ID token is available in client applications, not resource-servers. In the later, you only have the access-token. You should define an Auth0 "rule" to enrich access-tokens with the data you need and you'll find it in spring security-context (`JwtAuthenticationToken` instance or whatever else you define with `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do little bit changes to make it working.

I will explain by step - by - step :

I have created an account and have registered a regular web application with the name **test-app** in the Auth0 portal.

Now, I took help of the resource links provided for **Auth0 client** and **Resource Server** by Auth0 to setup Spring boot app and these are given below.

1. [Auth0 Client Spring Boot App Quick Start](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-boot/interactive)
2. [Auth0 Resource Server Spring Boot App Quick Start](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/01-authorization)

---

Now, I will explain through use cases.

I have created a Auth0 spring boot client (separate project).

application.properties :

```
server:
  port: 3000
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          auth0:
            client-id: <<id>>
            client-secret: <<secret>>
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: https://<<name>>.us.auth0.com/
```

Note: You can find **client id, client secret and issuer uri** from **Applications -> Open the app -> Settings.**

Now, I need to extract ID token which contains the user info, so I have created a sample controller and have used `OidcUser` to get that token:

```
@RestController
public class Resource {

    @GetMapping("/token")
    public void profile(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
        System.out.println(oidcUser.getIdToken().getTokenValue());
    }

}
```

As soon as I run the server and send the request to the `/token`, it will first redirect to the Auth0 login page. I have used my Google account to login and after successful login, it prints the ID JWT token.

**Note:** This client project is just show how I got the ID token. Not to confuse that resource server is also a client.

[image]

Now, coming to resource server, I have created a resource server Spring Boot App (separate project).

application.properties :

```
server:
  port: 3010
auth0:
  audience: https://<<name>>.auth0.com/api/v2/  
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://<<name>>.us.auth0.com/ 
          audiences:
          - https://<<name>>.us.auth0.com/api/v2/
```

SecurityConfig (You don't need to add any extra validator, i.e remove the AudienceValidator):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt(jwt -> jwtDecoder());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withIssuer);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

A sample Controller to show my case :

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @GetMapping("/profile")
    public void profile() {
        Jwt user = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(user.getClaimAsString("email") + " " + user.getClaimAsString("name"));
    }
}
```

As soon as I have run the server, hit the uri `/profile` with **Bearer token** as **ID token** like this :

[image]

The Spring Security is consuming this `Jwt` automatically and setting the `Principal` at this `Jwt` Object and you can extract this via `SecurityContextHolder`.

Note: In the claims map, you have all of your user info.

[image]

Output :

[image]

**Note:** ID token are not safe to be used in any cases. It can be used only in the case where you want to show/get user profile data but it should be avoided for all other use cases.

Comment: Making a resource-server also a client and adding a call to authorization-server for each and every request introduces way too much overhead. See my answer to add user data to access-tokens instead.

Comment: @ch4mp I have edited. I have meant to say resource server not authorization server. I didn't add any client to the resource server.

Comment: You are using an ID token as access-token. This is [worst practice](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/) and also the reason why you had to write a dedicated client to get the ID-token instead of configuring Postman with OAuth2 security (which sets Bearer Authorization header with access-token as expected)

Comment: If the point of the question is using Auth0 user data in Spring resource-server security, your answer is missing the part where this data is added to Auth0 access-tokens.

Comment: @ch4mp I agreed with you are mentioning in your comment. Thanks for sharing the documentation on ID token vs Access token. I read it. It mentioned that ID token should only be used if you want to get user profile data which is exactly matching the use case where author wanted to get user name and email and I feel author can use ID token to get his job done.

Comment: @ch4mp But if ID token is used for some other purpose like calling API, then it's a bad practice. It's concern for security of the application. Probably, the use of ID token should be avoided.

Comment: As I understand, this is the exact point here: calling an OAuth2 secured API (resource-server) and having user details in Spring security context (`Authentication` instance) for access-control decisions. The good solution with JWTs is adding claims to access-tokens. Final dot.